# SSH remote machine and execute command

Tags: linux, ssh, su

I am sshing to a remote machine and executing a command but my $PATH on the remote machine is set to the $PATH of user in the original machine and not that of sshed machine. But if I ssh to the remote machine and execute echo $PATH, it is set correctly to the logged in user in the new machine

```
root@host1> ssh admin@remotemachine echo $PATH
```

This prints the PATH of the user, in this case root on host1 and not admin on remotemachine

```
root@host1> ssh admin@remotemachine 
admin@remotemachine's password: ****
echo $PATH
```

Above works fine

Basically it's not changing the environment to the new user on remote machine. Somehow even though i am logged in to remote machine, it preserves the environment of root from host1. If I do ls -al /, it shows the directories from the remote machine, which means i am logged in to the remote machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use `set -x` to debug what we actually run:

```
$ set -x
$ ssh localhost echo $PATH
+ ssh localhost echo /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

The line with the `+` tells us that the command we *actually* run is:

```
ssh localhost echo /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Unsurprisingly, this is also the value we get back, regardless of what the remote `PATH` is.

We can single quote the command to ensure that we send `echo $PATH` instead of `echo /usr/local/bin:...` to the server:

```
$ ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'
+ ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'
```

Now `set -x` shows that `ssh` is being run with the unexpanded command instead of the expanded command, and we get the remote `PATH` in return.

Comment: That prints different $PATH, but still it's not same as what it printing if I ssh to remote machine and then execute echo $PATH on remote machine console.

Comment: That's most likely a configuration problem on the remote host. You can try to work around it with `ssh -tt you@yourhost bash -ilc "'echo \$PATH'"` to fake an interactive login shell with a tty.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-t`:

```
ssh admin@remotemachine -t 'echo $PATH'
```

From the man page:

```
 -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a
         remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
         options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

The explanation is a bit cryptic, but it will execute whatever you put in quotes. Single quotes are important so that `$PATH` does not expand before being executed.

Comment: @PMat, what do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens when you run that command? Output would be helpful.